# Unexpected keyword argument in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render the url of the movie clicked among numerous other movies. The url should be in the format
url/moviename. However, I am getting this error

```
movie_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'movie_name'
```

Please help me.... I am very new to Django, as you can see.

views code:

```
def movie_detail(request, movie_name):
    movieneed = movies.objects.get(title = movie_name)
    movieneed = movieneed.replace("_", " ")
    return render(request, 'app/movie.html', {'movie':movieneed})
```

template code:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
    <li data-id="{{ movie.id }}"><span class="title">
    <a href="{% url "movie" movie_name=movie.movie_name %}">


    {{ movie.title }}</a></span> ({{ movie.year }}) - {{ movie.genre}}<a class="delete">X</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```

url code:

```
url(r'^(?P<movie_name>)/$', views.movie_detail, name='movie'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily, that exception would mean that you don't have a `movie_name` parameter in your `movie_detail` function, but clearly you do.

I'm not positive, but I *think* the problem may be that you don't actually have anything to match in there. For example, say you only allow movie titles with letters, numbers, and hyphens (no punctuation, spaces, etc.) Then you need to use a regular expression like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<movie_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.movie_detail, name='movie')
```

Comment: This solved my problem. But just for alphanumeric characters. I used .+ for all characters. It was fine. But now I need my url to display /movietitle However, although it accepts any character it replaces those characters with %20. I need to display all those characters as they are except for space which I need to replace by '_'. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: If the questions was solved, please,  upvote and mark correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on the url regex. read this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups), can be helpful.

```
url(r'^(?P<movie_name>)/$', views.movie_detail, name='movie'),
```

To:

```
url(r'^(?P<movie_name>[\w-]+)/$', views.movie_detail, name='movie'),
```

> Named groups¶
>
> The above example used simple, non-named regular-expression groups
>   (via parenthesis) to capture bits of the URL and pass them as
>   positional arguments to a view. In more advanced usage, it’s possible
>   to use named regular-expression groups to capture URL bits and pass
>   them as keyword arguments to a view.
>
> In Python regular expressions, the syntax for named regular-expression
>   groups is (?Ppattern), where name is the name of the group and
>   pattern is some pattern to match.

Comment: This solved my problem. But just for alphanumeric characters. I used .+ for all characters. It was fine. But now I need my url to display /movietitle However, although it accepts any character it replaces those characters with %20. I need to display all those characters as they are except for space which I need to replace by '_'. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the movie name in the url for a [slug field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#slugfield), slugs are specially suited fields to convert arbitrary strings into valid url strings

as for your problem, your url is not getting properly matched, try this:

```
url(r'^(?P<movie_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.movie_detail, name='movie'),
```

Comment: This solved my problem. But just for alphanumeric characters. I used .+ for all characters. It was fine. But now I need my url to display
/movietitle
However, although it accepts any character it replaces those characters with %20. I need to display all those characters as they are except for space which I need to replace by '_'.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: the Django slugify (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.text) method handles all of this for you, don't try to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: yea. but it replaces every special characters with "-". I need to display the characters as they are except for space. 
But hey thank you :)